# M2 Add fields to custom payment method [ship to multiple address]

Tags: magento2, custom, payment-methods, payment, multishipping

I have created a custom payment method, which is working fine, but when i select ship to different address, than payment method was not appearing.
I added "allow_multiple_address" to 1.
Now payment method label is visible but the custom input field and custom button is missing.
It is also creating a invoice automatically